# Integration Flex sdk with Eclipse or Netbeans

Tags: apache-flex, eclipse, flex4

I want to know how can we integrate flex with eclipse and netbeans. I want to know steps. I want an help on this.

Answer (score 0):

If you build an Eclipse RCP application, you can use an HTML widget in your UI to host/embed your Flex component.

Comment: basically can u tell me steps i have searching for this from last couple of days. what i did is, downloaded the flex sdk and built an ant file and.mxml file and then executed that ant file. but it is giving me an error i am really stuck into this.

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood your question. Though you were trying to get a Flex component to run into an Eclipse application. Sounds more like you have a Eclipse config issue with Flex. Can't help much with that one. You may want to post your error message...

Comment: this is the error which i am getting while running an ant file
"
[exec] Loading configuration file C:\AdobeSdk\Flex\4.0\frameworks\flex-config.xml

[exec] Adobe Flex Compiler (mxmlc)

[exec] Version 4.0.0 build 14159

[exec] Copyright (c) 2004-2009 Adobe Systems, Inc. All rights reserved.

[exec] Error: unable to open 'Settings\muhammadsul\workspace\Flex\sample.mxml'

[exec] Use 'mxmlc -help' for information about using the command line.
"

Comment: May be you are rite about config issue of Eclipse with flex.

Comment: You may want to try Flash Builder instead, that should work out of the box